# What cues or clues can we look for to work out the context in which "ya" is being used?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones

After reading a brief explanation about the versatility of the word "ya" in Spanish, and how it can basically be used in different contexts to express ideas relating to the past, present and future (I don't know if this is also something that exists in English), I feel a little bit nervous about trying to read sentences that uses the word without misunderstanding the true intent of the writer or speaker.

Are there things you can definitely look out for that indicates what "ya" means in a particular context as it relates to the timing of the event or concept? Or is it something that is best interpreted in the context of the sentence?

I am not looking for absolute rules, just ideas from native speakers that might be more familiar with how it is commonly used.

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in the dictionary https://dle.rae.es/ya?m=form They give you many clues to how it is used.

Comment: I would say that when part of a sentence, the meaning that keeps the most meaning, most often is reading it as "already".

Comment: El contexto te da la información necesaria para descifrar el significado

Answer (score 1):

Let us look at the first few examples in [the dictionary](https://dle.rae.es/ya?m=form)

> 1. adv. En tiempo u ocasión pasados. Ya hemos hablado de esto más de una vez.

Look at the verb. This is clearly a past usage. We have spoken about this more than once.

> 2. adv. Inmediatamente, ahora mismo. U. t. en sent. enfático. Aumento de salarios, ya.

Pay rise, now. This can also refer to the immediate past *Ya pagué* I just paid.

> 3. adv. En el tiempo presente, haciendo relación al pasado. Era muy rico, pero ya es pobre.

Again fairly clear. He used to be rich but he is poor now.

4. adv. En tiempo u ocasión futuros. Ya nos veremos. Ya se hará eso.

More difficult to give an English translation as we would probably leave it out.

5. adv. Finalmente o últimamente. Ya es preciso tomar una resolución.

Now is the time to decide (after all that has happened/been discussed)

6. adv. Luego, inmediatamente. U. cuando se responde a quien llama. Ya voy. Ya van.

I am coming. If we wanted to emphasise in English we might say Yeah, yeah, I cam coming. They are just going.

In all these cases I think the verb tense gives a strong clue and the overall context helps enormously. There are lots more examples in the reference but these may give you a start.